# Viscosity of a fluid with TikZ or PStricks or other packages for students of a high school

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, pstricks, asymptote, animations

The viscosity is a physical quantity indicated with the Greek letter `η` which refers to fluids and gases and represents the resistance of a fluid to flow.

In the net there are different images where the concept of viscosity is explained. I could create the images with Mathcha but according to your creativity in `LaTeX`, I would like to show my students, even with an animation, the viscosity in relation to the figures below. Thank you very much everyone.

[image: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTeCobEseJgLQQ-Ok7ZaYgHoIeEkrdC1O0S9OGsiv6QFm-OiVGb&usqp=CAU]

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2Goavlxc_Me5okGt_sZ-fz4qvOtLGzsHFok947UQN-6MjQixg5F6_0pSFGBwhFAUDmnuJ_OuGac2JFmhmkvMK-66zqFX]

I add my MWE,

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Cube [id:dp8492544147077676] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (102,188) -- (174,116) -- (291.5,116) -- (291.5,127) -- (219.5,199) -- (102,199) -- cycle ; \draw   (291.5,116) -- (219.5,188) -- (102,188) ; \draw   (219.5,188) -- (219.5,199) ;
%Shape: Cube [id:dp3646686385101303] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (111.5,178.46) -- (173.96,116) -- (291.5,116) -- (291.5,125.54) -- (229.04,188) -- (111.5,188) -- cycle ; \draw   (291.5,116) -- (229.04,178.46) -- (111.5,178.46) ; \draw   (229.04,178.46) -- (229.04,188) ;
%Shape: Cube [id:dp8548923286577379] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (128.5,168.46) -- (190.96,106) -- (308.5,106) -- (308.5,115.54) -- (246.04,178) -- (128.5,178) -- cycle ; \draw   (308.5,106) -- (246.04,168.46) -- (128.5,168.46) ; \draw   (246.04,168.46) -- (246.04,178) ;
%Shape: Cube [id:dp9271648006556463] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (144.5,158.46) -- (206.96,96) -- (324.5,96) -- (324.5,105.54) -- (262.04,168) -- (144.5,168) -- cycle ; \draw   (324.5,96) -- (262.04,158.46) -- (144.5,158.46) ; \draw   (262.04,158.46) -- (262.04,168) ;
%Shape: Cube [id:dp7317737198627721] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (162.5,148.46) -- (224.96,86) -- (342.5,86) -- (342.5,95.54) -- (280.04,158) -- (162.5,158) -- cycle ; \draw   (342.5,86) -- (280.04,148.46) -- (162.5,148.46) ; \draw   (280.04,148.46) -- (280.04,158) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da544553702567177] 
\draw    (89,165) -- (89.45,135) ;
\draw [shift={(89.5,132)}, rotate = 450.87] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5553452645980281] 
\draw    (89,165) -- (88.54,202) ;
\draw [shift={(88.5,205)}, rotate = 270.72] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4092251015809141] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=3]    (165.21,106) -- (210.71,106) ;
\draw [shift={(216.71,106)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (18.75,-9.01) -- (0,0) -- (18.75,9.01) -- (12.45,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da20993884080259373] 
\draw    (89.5,132) -- (185.5,132.46) ;
%Shape: Cube [id:dp19016897937864674] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (185.5,138.46) -- (247.96,76) -- (365.5,76) -- (365.5,85.54) -- (303.04,148) -- (185.5,148) -- cycle ; \draw   (365.5,76) -- (303.04,138.46) -- (185.5,138.46) ; \draw   (303.04,138.46) -- (303.04,148) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5986734259342672] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=3]    (303.04,138.46) -- (413.5,138.97) ;
\draw [shift={(419.5,139)}, rotate = 180.27] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 139; green, 87; blue, 42 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (18.75,-9.01) -- (0,0) -- (18.75,9.01) -- (12.45,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9278072671355249] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=3]    (280.04,158) -- (361.5,158) ;
\draw [shift={(367.5,158)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (18.75,-9.01) -- (0,0) -- (18.75,9.01) -- (12.45,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da24576074460285446] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 189; green, 16; blue, 224 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=3]    (246.04,178) -- (306.5,178.91) ;
\draw [shift={(312.5,179)}, rotate = 180.86] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 189; green, 16; blue, 224 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (18.75,-9.01) -- (0,0) -- (18.75,9.01) -- (12.45,0) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (91.25,151.9) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$h$};
% Text Node
\draw (173,84.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$\mathbf{F}$};
% Text Node
\draw (267.25,89.9) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$S$};
% Text Node
\draw (385,113.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$\mathbf{v}$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, can you make your question more precise? What would you like to animate?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat To animate the planes of the surfaces that flow differently in fuction of to the height as the first image (for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a primitive example of an animation, which shows what happens if you increase the viscosity. The various parameters are stored in pgf keys (except for the number of layers because the `parse=true` option of `foreach` doesn't work well with integers). The bounding box gets recorded in the aux file.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{recycle bounding box/.style={%
execute at end picture={%
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\tikz@bbox@figbb@#1{%
{\the\pgf@picminx,\the\pgf@picminy,\the\pgf@picmaxx,\the\pgf@picmaxy}}\relax}},
execute at begin picture={%
\ifcsname tikz@bbox@figbb@#1\endcsname
 \edef\figbb{\csname tikz@bbox@figbb@#1\endcsname}%
 \path ({\figbb[0]},{\figbb[1]})  ({\figbb[2]},{\figbb[3]});
\fi}}}  
\makeatother
\tikzset{pics/3d layer/.style={code={
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d layer/##1}}
 \tikzset{/tikz/3d layer/.cd,#1}
 \path[3d layer/all,3d layer/fore] (-\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,-\pv{z}/2)
    -- (\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,-\pv{z}/2)
    -- (\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2)
    -- (-\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) -- cycle;
 \path[3d layer/all,3d layer/side] (\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,-\pv{z}/2)
    -- (\pv{x}/2,\pv{y}/2,-\pv{z}/2)
    -- (\pv{x}/2,\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2)
    -- (\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) -- cycle;
 \path[3d layer/all,3d layer/top] (-\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2)
    -- (\pv{x}/2,-\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2)
    -- (\pv{x}/2,\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2)
    -- (-\pv{x}/2,\pv{y}/2,\pv{z}/2) -- cycle;
 }},
 3d layer/.cd,x/.initial=2,y/.initial=2,z/.initial=0.2,
 fore/.style={},
 side/.style={},
 top/.style={},
 all/.style={draw,fill=blue!20},
 }
\begin{document}
\foreach \Z in {1,...,40}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,recycle bounding box=A]
\begin{scope}[3d view={30}{10},declare function={mu=1+\Z/20;
    zboundary=0.1;zfluid=0.2;}]
 \def\Nlayer{6} 
 \path pic{3d layer={all/.append style={fill=gray!60},z=zboundary}}
 foreach \Y in {0,...,\Nlayer}
 {(0.1*\Y/mu,0,zboundary+\Y*zfluid) pic{3d layer={z=zfluid}}}
 (0.1*\Nlayer/mu,0,\Nlayer*zfluid+zfluid) 
 pic{3d layer={all/.append style={fill=gray!60},z=zboundary}}
 ;
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Spectacular! But why is the movement from right to left? Shouldn't scrolling be from left to right? Where can I put the labels in your code?

Comment: Why when I compile your code the figure is stop?

Comment: @Sebastiano You have to compile twice to get the bounding box in. This is a primitive example to have a more concrete basis of discussions. But yes, AFAIK if you *increase* the viscosity it will be harder to "distort" the medium.

Comment: For me it is incomprehensible :-) your comment. I am not an expert in this field. 
I don't understand how you animate the image.

Comment: You shouldn't really try this, but if you swim in honey you will be slower than when you swim in honey liquor. ;-)

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I have forgot to check mark :-(